# Bootstrap nav hover not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I tried to change color on hover but its not working please help me with this its draining my time

```css
nav div ul li:hover
{
  background-color: red;
}

//when i tried the answer they gave

.navbar .dropdown >li>a:hover{
  background:red;
}

please view the image for result
```

```html
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="default_profile"><img src="assets/img/default_user.png"/></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Username <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user fa-sm"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog fa-sm"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Settings</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-lock fa-sm"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
       
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: You can try adding the "!important" flag to your background-color. background-color: red !important;

Comment: This is probably because the more specific style that bootstrap uses overrides the generic "div ul li....".

Comment: tried that but its not working... is there any other solution

Comment: Is your CSS included after bootstrap.css?

Comment: Yea its added after bootstrap.css

Comment: but i even swapped it same result

Answer (score 0):

it should be on

```
a:hover { background-color: red; }
```

since your aiming for the anchor tag not the li item.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find out what your elements name is by right clicking on the element and clicking on inspect in browsers like chrome, firefox, and IE.  The following should work.

```
.navbar-nav>li>a:hover{
  background:red;
}
```

If you want to be more specific you can state it like the following:

```
.navbar-nav>li>a.dropdown-toggle:hover{
  background:red;
}
```

Comment: Did you try what I have posted in my edited answer it is working here https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/gqc634uc/